# Spinning Social Media Icons - bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to add Social Button Footer same as this Code:(https://codepen.io/vpdemo/pen/WbMNJv), But my Buttons are not Circle, How Should I Fix?

```css
 a, a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.socialbtns, .socialbtns ul, .socialbtns li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px;
}

.socialbtns li {
    list-style: none outside none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.socialbtns .fa {
    color: #FFF;
 background-color: #000;
 width: 40px;
    height: 28px;
    padding-top: 12px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -o-border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
   transform: rotate(-360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
}

.socialbtns .fa:hover {
 transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
 transform: rotate(360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 4 Website Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

<br/>
<div align="center" class="socialbtns">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-google-plus"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-github"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-pinterest"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-linkedin"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-instagram"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-youtube"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed only height. Height and width were different. `height: 40px;`

```css
 a, a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.socialbtns, .socialbtns ul, .socialbtns li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px;
}

.socialbtns li {
    list-style: none outside none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.socialbtns .fa {
    color: #FFF;
 background-color: #000;
 width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 12px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -o-border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
   transform: rotate(-360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
}

.socialbtns .fa:hover {
 transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
 transform: rotate(360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 4 Website Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

<br/>
<div align="center" class="socialbtns">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-google-plus"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-github"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-pinterest"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-linkedin"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-instagram"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="fa fa-lg fa-youtube"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```